# Battery equalizing charge

Tags: battery-charging

[image]

Is he referring to the cell voltages when said "brings all cells to similar levels" highlighted

Source:

ARC-FLASH HANDBOOK SERIES III

Published By NETA (InterNational Electrical Testing Association)

Sponsored by CBS ArcSafe, Inc.

Comment: Yes.  Individual cells in a battery experience different chemical reactions.  Sulfation means cells don't fully charge so must be floated to remove sulfer.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat can you make your answer official?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Individual cells in a battery experience different chemical reactions. Sulfation means cells don't fully charge so must be floated to remove sulfur.

IEEE defines equalization voltage as *the voltage, higher than float, applied to a battery to correct inequalities among battery cells (voltage or specific gravity)*.  The equalization voltage depends upon battery chemistry.

[IEEE Recommended Practice for Maintenance, Testing, and Replacement of Vented Lead-Acid Batteries for Stationary Applications](https://pdf4pro.com/cdn/ieee-std-450-450tm-eee-standards-ieee-standards-247773.pdf)

> Equalizing charge

> When an individual cell voltage corrected for temperature is below 2.13 V, (typical for nominal 1.215 S.G. cells) or the specific gravity corrected for temperature falls below the manufacturer’s limit, corrective action should be initiated. It can be accomplished by providing an equalizing charge to the entire battery. However,
> it is often more convenient to apply the equalizing charge to the individual cell. This may be done during normal float operation of the battery.